# Cannot "use" in clojurescript repl

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I type the following at the Clojurescript namespace.

```
cljs.user> (use '[clojure.zip :only [insert-child]])

WARNING: Use of undeclared Var cljs.user/use at line 1 
"Error evaluating:" (use (quote [clojure.zip :only [insert-child]])) :as "cljs.user.use.call(null,cljs.core.vec([\"\\uFDD1'clojure.zip\",\"\\uFDD0'only\",cljs.core.vec([\"\\uFDD1'insert-child\"])]));\n"
#<TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined>
TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.js:32728:147), <anonymous>:1:85)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.js:32728:147), <anonymous>:6:3)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.js:32728:142
    at evaluate_javascript (http://localhost:3000/main.js:32741:4)
    at Object.callback (http://localhost:3000/main.js:32806:138)
    at goog.messaging.AbstractChannel.deliver (http://localhost:3000/main.js:31059:13)
    at goog.net.xpc.CrossPageChannel.deliver_ (http://localhost:3000/main.js:32164:14)
    at Function.goog.net.xpc.NativeMessagingTransport.messageReceived_ (http://localhost:3000/main.js:31732:13)
    at goog.events.Listener.handleEvent (http://localhost:3000/main.js:22590:26)
    at Object.goog.events.fireListener (http://localhost:3000/main.js:22924:21)
nil
```

It seems to be stating that the 'use' method does not exist in the cljs.user namespace. This kind of makes sense to me, as Clojurescript itself cannot evaluate Clojure expressions. However, I know that Clojurescript has a clojure.zip namespace, I have used clojure.zip in the namespace declaration as `(:use [clojure.zip :only [insert-child]])`.

How do I use the Clojurescript version of clojure.zip in the Clojurescript repl?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because ClojureScript namespaces are implemented completely differently than Clojure, ClojureScript does not support the `use` or `require` forms directly.

Instead, you *must* use the `ns` macro. To use `clojure.zip` in the `cljs.user` namespace, then, just do the following:

```
(ns cljs.user (:use [clojure.zip :only [insert-child]]))
```

Note that the forms supported in the ClojureScript version of `ns` are a subset of those supported in Clojure; specifically, `:use` clauses *must* specify an `:only` form, and the `:require` clause must specify an `:as` form.

Comment: just a heads up, I just ran up against this same problem in 2016 still, trying to `(require ...)` some debug tools in the middle of my code